# Let $u,v,w \in \mathbb{R}^3$, and define the matrix $A$ such that

Tags: linear-algebra

$$
    A =\begin{pmatrix}
    \uparrow & \uparrow & \uparrow \\
    u & v & w \\
    \downarrow & \downarrow & \downarrow \\
    \end{pmatrix}
, $$

$$
    rref(A) =\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 2 \\
    0 & 1 & 3 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
Consider the following statements.

(I) The vector $w$ belongs to span{$u$}.

(II) The vector $w$ belongs to span{$v$}.

(III) The vector $w$ belongs to span{$u,v$}.

How many of the above statements are always true?

I'm sure that (I) and (II) can't be true. But I'm not too sure if (III) can always be true. Need some help with explanation here, thanks.

Comment: Statements (I) and (II) are identical.  Typo?

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh Your comment should be an answer, I think.

Comment: @saulspatz yes is a typo, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the system of linear equations,
$$\lambda_1 u + \lambda_2 v + \lambda_3 w = 0.$$
If you turn it into an augmented matrix, you get $A$, with a $0$ column augmented. The reduced row-echelon form therefore describes the general solution for $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3$.

The equations in the reduced row-echelon are
\begin{align*}
\lambda_1 + 2\lambda_3 &= 0 \\
\lambda_2 + 3\lambda_3 &= 0.
\end{align*}
Let $t = -\lambda_3$. Then $\lambda_1 = 2t$, $\lambda_2 = 3t$, and $\lambda_3 = -t$, where $t \in \mathbb{R}$. These are all possibilities. If $t = 0$, we get a degenerate, unhelpful solution. If $t \neq 0$, then we have
$$2tu + 3tv - tw = 0 \iff 2u + 3v - w = 0 \iff w = 2u + 3v.$$
So, $w \in \operatorname{span}\{u,v\}$. If we had $w \in \operatorname{span}\{u\}$, then we would have to have a solution with $\lambda_2 = 0$ and $\lambda_3 = -1$, which is not the case. Similarly, $w \notin \operatorname{span}\{v\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, all the three vectors u,v and w are in a plane (in particular the XY plane). Therefore, you have to find two linearly independent vectors which will make basis for the plane and hence the third one will be in the span of the other two. Now, if you look carefully, u,v,w are pairwise linearly independent and hence any two of the three vectors can form a basis for the plane, Eventually, the third vector will be in the span of the other two. Therefore, option (III) is correct. w is in the span of {u,v}.